# WinApi Window abnormal destruction after multiple creations

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm refactoring **C** implementation of a screen effect, obtained by shifting the bits of a desktop snapshot.

The code was inspired from this video: [Screen Melting Effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrBxr0PD4xo)

I've wrapped the code in a singleton class called *ScreenMelter*:

```
class ScreenMelter
{
private:
    HWND hWnd;
    static unsigned int TimerID;

    static unsigned int nScreenWidth;
    static unsigned int nScreenHeight;
protected:

    bool InitClass()
    {
        WNDCLASS wndClass = { 0, MelterProc, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), 0, NULL, L"Melter" };

        if (!GetClassInfo(GetModuleHandle(NULL), L"Melter", &wndClass))
        {
            if (!RegisterClass(&wndClass))
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot register class!", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool InitWindow()
    {
        nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

        hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Melter", NULL, WS_POPUP, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

        if (!hWnd)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot create window!", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void FreeWindow()
    {
        if (hWnd)
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    }

    void FreeClass()
    {
        UnregisterClass(L"Melter", GetModuleHandle(NULL));
    }

    static LRESULT WINAPI MelterProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (Msg)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            std::cout << "I got created! \n";

            HDC hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);
            HDC hdcDesktop = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);

            BitBlt(hdcWindow, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, hdcDesktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);
            ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdcDesktop);

            TimerID = SetTimer(hWnd, 0,
                1,      // Speed of the timer
                NULL);

            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
            break;
        }
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL);
            break;
        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            HDC hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

            int nWidth = (rand() % 150);

            int nYPos = (rand() % 15);
            int nXPos = (rand() % nScreenWidth) - (150 / 2);

            BitBlt(hdcWindow, nXPos, nYPos, nWidth, nScreenHeight, hdcWindow, nXPos, 0, SRCCOPY);

            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);
            break;
        }
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if (wParam != VK_ESCAPE)
                break;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE:
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            // It kills the timer, but I wonder, why that doens't responde after one call
            KillTimer(hWnd, TimerID);

            TimerID = NULL;
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            std::cout << "-> I got destroyed!\n";
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
        }

        return 0;
    }

public:

    void StartMelting(int32_t duration)
    {
        InitClass();
        InitWindow();

        MSG Msg = { 0 };

        auto Start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                DispatchMessage(&Msg);
                std::cout << "Msg ";
            }

            auto End = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

            if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(End - Start).count() >= duration) break;
        }

        FreeWindow();
        FreeClass();
    }

protected:
    ScreenMelter()
    { }
public:
    ScreenMelter(const ScreenMelter&) = delete;
    ScreenMelter& operator=(const ScreenMelter&) = delete;

    static ScreenMelter& GetInstance()
    {
        static ScreenMelter melter;
        return melter;
    }

    ~ScreenMelter()
    {
        FreeWindow();
        FreeClass();
    }
};
```

The class works as it should, but only on the first creation of the window. After some debugging, I've found out that after the fist call to *StartMelting(seconds)*, the window gets created corectly, but shortly after it receives a `WM_DESTROY/WM_CLOSE` message that closes it.

The following code shows this:

```
int main() 
{
    ScreenMelter& melter = ScreenMelter::GetInstance();

    int input;
    int32_t TimeInSeconds(2);
    while (1)
    {
        std::cin >> input;

        if (input == 0)
            break;

        melter.StartMelting(TimeInSeconds);
    }
}
```

After staring at the screen for almost an hour, I've decied that I need some help.

### Question:

- What causes the window to receive a close message after the first
  creation of the window ? The resources are freed corectly after the
  timer expires, or `ESC` key is pressed !

### EDIT 1:

To make my question more clear, here's the output of the aplication:

```
// First call
1
I got created!
Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg
Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg
Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg
Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg
Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg
Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg
Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg Msg -> I got destroyed!
// Second call
1
I got created!
Msg -> I got destroyed!  
// Third call
1
I got created!
Msg -> I got destroyed!
```

Comment: Fyi, you're returning a DefWindowProc call even *after* you handled the message(s). Check your documentation; that isn't right. You generally only call DefWindowProc when you *don't* handle a message.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], don't just dump The Code.

Comment: I've replaced *breaks* in the switch with `return 0;` (Signals that the message was processed), and I still have the same problem: _The program works only on the first initialization_

Comment: @Lundin It is initialized with _false_ in the constructor !

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah I noticed after reading more carefully, so nevermind.

Comment: You call `FreeClass` at the bottom of `StartMelting`, which unregisters the class, but you never reset `init` back to false so next time around the window creation will fail as the class isn't registered.

Comment: That's what you get for storing redundant state. `init` is unneeded, and its sole purpose is to introduce a bug. This is an anti-pattern, that's best dealt with using the RAII idiom. No reason to keep track of which parts of a class instance are valid. RAII ensures that a class instance is either valid, or does not exist.

Comment: @IInspectable You're right ! The design of the class is poor and I will improve it, but the functionality of the program stil doesn't work !

Comment: So then, provide a [mcve]. If nothing else, it'll help you identify the root cause of the issue. The link provides helpful tips on how to construct an MCVE. The call to `GetAsyncKeyState` is also less than optimal. You're already running a message loop, so why not respond to `WM_KEYDOWN` for the [ESC] key with a `PostQuitMessage` call? That way you won't miss any key presses, because it does not rely sampling. Sampling will miss any events that happen in between sampling points.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, all of those were design problems, but I still can't understand why the program doesn't run correctly after the first time. The window gets created and closed immediatly

Comment: Providing a [mcve] would have helped you narrow down the source of the issue. And it would make for a far better question, that's a lot more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @IInspectable I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49666930/edit) link underneath your question, so that you don't have to hold off until your next question. There's no better time to improve than now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you process the `WM_DESTROY` message, you use `PostQuitMessage`. Don't.

The `WM_QUIT` message is then processed later, the second HWND is already created, but immediately destroyed because you exit the loop in `StartMelting`.

There are **many** problems with your code.
Just one, for information: `UnregisterClass` fails when a window is still alive.

Comment: Yes, you have to UnregisterClass only after you've succesfully destroyed the window!  
What could I use instead of `PostQuitMessage` ?

Comment: Just delete the line. Works fine, here.

Comment: The explanation is not quite correct. `WM_QUIT` is processed in order, before the next window instance is created. However, the `WM_QUIT` message is not a real message. It's more like a flag, and once `PostQuitMessage` is called, that flag stays set. During the next loop, the window gets created just fine, but the `WM_QUIT` message is still there, so it gets torn down immediately. See [Why is there a special PostQuitMessage function?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453) for more details.

Comment: @IInspectable  I don't understand what you mean by `processed in order, before the next window instance is created`. I added a `cout << "msg " << Msg.message;` to the code, and see WM_QUIT peaked after the next creation. By processed, I meant "by the OP's code"

Comment: The order of events is: Window class registered -> window created -> [ESC] pressed -> `PostQuitMessage` is called -> window is destroyed -> window class is unregistered. The code then loops back to the start: Windows class is registered -> window is created -> `WM_QUIT` is processed (because it's still there) -> window is destroyed -> window class is unregistered. Everything happens in order. No messages are handled by the 'wrong' window instance, as your answer suggests (*"The `WM_QUIT` message is then processed later"*).

Comment: @IInspectable I still don't understand. I never pressed [ESC] when tracking down the problem. The only WM_QUIT messages I saw was the ones caused by `PostQuitMessage` in the `WM_DESTROY` code, and that's the only place the API is used, and they were peeked after the next window creation. My answer does NOT suggest that a `WM_QUIT` message is handled by "a wrong window instance". The `hwnd` value in the `MSG` struct  for `WM_QUIT` is NULL, anyway...

Comment: There's a fallthrough from the `WM_KEYDOWN` handler into that same code. If you closed the window through the close button instead, the only thing that changes is the order of destroying the window and calling `PostQuitMessage`. After handling the first `WM_QUIT` message, the window is (attempted to be) destroyed, and the window class is unregistered. Everything is in order. I guess I'm just having difficulty understanding what you meant by *"The `WM_QUIT` message is then processed **later**"*, which is partly true, yet inaccurate.

Comment: Just make a project with the OP's code. and add some `cout` instructions to trace what is done and when. I did. You'll see that "The WM_QUIT message is then processed later". But let's agree to disagree.

Comment: It is processed **again**, at a later time. The way you phrased it strongly suggests, that it is only processed, once a new window instance had been created. I'm not saying that that's what you meant, but that's what it reads.